# Why should the vectors in Dixon's factorization algorithm be linearly dependant?

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, proof-writing, algorithms, prime-factorization

[Wikipedia's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dixon%27s_factorization_method) for Dixon's factorization method (in algorithm paragraph) states the following:

> ...we can use the methods of linear algebra (for example, Gaussian elimination) to multiply together these various relations in such a way that...

In case I use gaussian elimination I suppose I would have to use linearly dependant vectors.

The question is a bit weird but: why should those vectors be linearly dependant? Is it because of the method used or does the factorization algorithm require it? Is there a mathematically proven justification for that?

Comment: The idea is to get a nontrivial solution $x^2\equiv y^2\mod n$, so modulo $2$ we must get the zero-vector, hence the vectors must be linear dependent over $\mathbb (Z_2)^k$

Comment: @Peter Wow, and I thought it was something more complex. I was definitely overthinking it. Thank you a lot!